# Laravel Socialite Call Back Redirect To Login Again After Auth Login

Tags: laravel, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, laravel-socialite, laravel-authentication

I'm using Laravel socialiteproviders Microsoft for authentication. The callback is working fine and user details also return correctly. But after I check some conditions and redirect to user profile it navigates to login again.

```
public function Callback($provider) {

    $userSocial = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    $user = User::where(['email' => $userSocial->getEmail()])->first();

    if($user) {

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->route('profile');
        
    } else {

        $user = User::create([
            'name'          => $userSocial->getName(),
            'email'         => $userSocial->getEmail(),
            'provider_id'   => $userSocial->getId(),
            'provider'      => $provider,
        ]);

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->route('profile');

    }

}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done to solve this problem? Which of the 2 branches is executed? Is the user successfully created?

Comment: @miken32 User creation is working fine. But logging session not working when redirect to `profile`